# setBitmapImage is not working in panasonic and one plus after image compression

Tags: java, android

This is the method where i'm setting the bitmap to imageView. This works properly for all the devices except oneplus and panasonic devices. It will show blank when i set the bitmap to imageView in oneplus and panasonic devices and the bitmap is not null. we thought android version might be the issue, but it worked fine for other devices with the same version.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

ImageView chatImageSendView; 

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

    ImageCompression imageCompressione = new ImageCompression(ChatWithImageActivity.this);
    String compressImagePath = imageCompressione.compressImage(fileUri.getPath());
    destination = new File(compressImagePath );

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ExifInterface exifCamera = null;
    try {
        exifCamera = new ExifInterface(fileUri.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientationCam = exifCamera.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Bitmap bmRotatedCam = rotateBitmap(bmp, orientationCam);

    if (bmRotatedCam != null) {
        chatImageSendView.setImageBitmap(bmRotatedCam);
    }
}
```

This class we are using for image compression.

```
public class ImageCompression {

    private Context context;
    private static final float maxHeight = 1280.0f;
    private static final float maxWidth = 1280.0f;


    public ImageCompression(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public String compressImage(String imagePath) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    if(bmp!=null)
    {
        bmp.recycle();
    }

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filepath = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        //write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filepath;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public String getFilename() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Medcync/ImageSent");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    String mImageName="IMG_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +".jpg";
    String uriString = (mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ 

mImageName);;
        return uriString;

    }
}
```

Below method is used to rotate the image

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bitmap;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I can see right away this is bad code.  Why are you rotating by creating a new Bitmap, if your only use is to set it in an ImageView?  Use ImageView.setImageMatrix instead.

Comment: Also, your createScaledBitmap function is way overcomplicated.  You're getting the bounds, then decoding it, then creating a new bitmap to the scaled bounds, then drawing it to that bitmap, then creating another copy of it and rotating it, then writing it to the filesystem.  Then later reopening the file?  Its like you decided to do everything in the least sensible way possible.  This code should be printed out so it can be burned, then rewritten.

Comment: Somebody found any solution? I can see the captured image in File Explorer, But setting bitmap not working on oneplus devices